# Navigation Drawer - ImageView issue with expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have a problem with my expandable listview. This is the first time i've implemented it. So, this is the problem:

I have a navigation drawer that is composed of 2 GroupView:
-First Element
-Second Element

Each GroupView is composed of a list of data. When i click the second element, the expandable list show me a list of data with a specific Image. When i click the first element, the expandable list show me a list of data with another specific image or maybe it could.

> This is the problem:
>
> When i click to Second Element and then click to first element, some of data in the First Element take the image of data of the list in the Second Element !

I want that when i click to the second element, the expandable list must show me a list of data with a specific image that i set e when i click to the first element the expandable list must show me the other list of data with another image that i set.

These are the two method in the CustomAdapter.class and the ViewHolder class:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(act).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view, null);
        
    }
    
    TextView transportName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parentTitle);
    ImageView transportIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parentIcon);
    
    transportName.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).getServiceName());
    transportIcon.setImageResource(getGroup(groupPosition).getIcon());

    
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(act).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view_child, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            
            viewHolder.lineName =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLineNameNavDrawer);
            viewHolder.lineDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLineDescNavDrawer);
            viewHolder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkLineNavDrawer);
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgLineNavDrawer);
            
            viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
                    getChild(groupPosition, getPosition).setChecked(buttonView.isChecked());
                    
                }
            });
            
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkLineNavDrawer, viewHolder.check);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        
        if(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getLinename().equals("Mostra aree di sosta"))
        {
            viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.parking);
        }
        else if(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getLinename().equals("Mostra bike sharing"))
        {
            viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bike);
        }
        else if(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getLinename().equals("Mostra rivenditori"))
        {
            viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ticket);
        }
        viewHolder.check.setTag(childPosition);
        viewHolder.lineName.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getLinename());
        viewHolder.lineDesc.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getDescription());
        viewHolder.check.setChecked(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).isChecked());
        
    return convertView;
}

 class ViewHolder { 
     TextView lineName; 
     TextView lineDesc; 
     ImageView icon;
     CheckBox check;
};
```

Layout of parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GroupLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/row_highlighter"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/parentIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/parentTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout of child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ChildLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".15"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLineNavDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/apiedi" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".7"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLineNameNavDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLineDescNavDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".15" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkLineNavDrawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Screen:

Second GroupView: http://i60.tinypic.com/ogjius.png

First GroupView: http://i61.tinypic.com/2ajtjdw.png

If anyone can help me, i'll appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.  You only instantiate it when `convertView == null`.  That means whenever `convertView != null` it's reusing the original `setOnCheckedChangeListener` which may or may not be using the same group position number.

Instead, always set a new `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.  Whether or not converView is null or not.  Just like you do with the `viewHolder.icon.setImageResource` invocations.

You also are storing two things in the convertView's tag.  No need to store R.id.checkLineNavDrawer directly as a tag when it's already being done in with the ViewHolder\

Got it.  You need an else for the image.  So if none of the getLinename().equals("blah") work, you can just set it to the walking man image.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. The problem isn't with the checkbox, what i want is that in the second group view the image view must contain that image and the first group view must contain only the image of the man that walk.
The problem is in viewHolder.icon.setImageResource i think

Comment: you'll still have a problem with that listener if any of the views are recycled.  You may not have seen that problem yet, but it is certainly there.

Comment: I've tried to put the setOnCheckedChangeListener out of the control, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you overwrite the getGroup and getChild method calls? Because otherwise, nothing else stands out as a red flag for your getGroupView and getChildView methods

Comment: Updated my answer for something else I noticed.  Still probably not the issue though

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with overwrite?

Comment: sorry, I mean override.

Comment: Yes, if you see the code that i've posted there are the Override at the beginning of the method

Comment: Yes, that's for the getGroupView() and getChildView() methods.  I'm talking about the getGroup() and getChild() methods.

Comment: Yes, all of the method in the CustomAdapter are override. If you see this image => http://i62.tinypic.com/2i7wirt.png

The problem is that image that i've indicated with an arrow. In that list, there must be only the image with the man that walk.